# $\phi : \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} $, $\overline{i} \to \phi(\overline{i})= \overline{i \pmod m}$ is a homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

**(True or False)** Let $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, +)$ with $m,n$ two positives integers. If $m|n$, then $\phi : \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} $, $\overline{i} \to \phi(\overline{i})= \overline{i \pmod m}$ is a homomorphism.

I don't know how I could verify or contradict this "conjecture". Is anyone is able to give me a hint to resolve this problem?

Comment: Where are you stuck? When stating your question like this, the problem could be a multitude of things: maybe you don't know the definition of homomorphism, maybe you're making a calculation mistake somewhere down the line, maybe something totally different. Please help us help you.

Comment: I am not able to start actually. I only need a hint for starting the problem.

Comment: you need to check whether the proposed map is well defined. Do you understand how?

Comment: No, can you help me at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$phi$ is defined through an arbitrary representative of each coset modulo $n$. You have to first check $\phi(i\bmod n)$ doesn't depend on the representative, so that $\phi$  is well defined.

Then you have to check $\phi(0\bmod n)=0\bmod m$ and $\;\phi(i\bmod n+j\bmod n)=\phi(i\bmod n)+\phi(j\bmod n)$, using the representatives.